# No existe el control GroupBox en silverlight

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

Tengo un proyecto para modificar en visual studio 2010 y no encuentro el control GroupBox y lo necesito para que en su propiedad visible se haga true o false dependiendo de una selección en un combobox.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

busque la referencia para adicionarla pero no esta el dll que dll se debe adicionar para que aparezca  el groupbox??

Comment: Silverlight *no* tiene un `GroupBox` por defecto, podes usar [Silverlight Contrib](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=silverlightcontrib#GroupBoxControl) que tiene uno y es gratis, o [crear el tuyo propio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232860/which-groupbox-control-would-you-recommend-for-silverlight).

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal hola esta para Visual Studio 2010??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas de un `GroupBox` para hacer visible o no un grupo de controles, puedes usar el `Grid` o `StackPanel` para poner controles dentro de este

[How to bind stackpanel visibility property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942889/how-to-bind-stackpanel-visibility-property)

[StackPanel Visibility Binding](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/66bfde48-88d9-45b7-b879-4edc95a02578/stackpanel-visibility-binding?forum=silverlightcontrols)

quizas no sea `bool (true/false)` lo que asignes a la visibilidad, pero puedes aplicar un `converted` para pasar estos a valores que reconoce la propiedad

Asi podrias

```
 <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel2" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
 </StackPanel>
```

asi podrias bindear con el model aplicando `MVVM`, digo si es que usas este patron

Comment: ya estaba con un contentPanel, pero definitivamente es mejor la opción que me dices, gracias